# Changes to a MySQL InnoDB table - which files are involved and why?

Tags: mysql, innodb, disaster-recovery

When changing the content of an InnoDB MySQL table the following files on the file system appears to be involved/changed:

- `/path/to/mysql/data/[database]/[table].ibd` (due to `innodb_file_per_table`)
- `/path/to/mysql/data/data/ib_logfile0`
- `/path/to/mysql/data/data/ib_logfile1`
- `/path/to/mysql/data/data/ibdata1`

For each of these files:

1. When is the file created?
2. When will the file be written to?
3. When will the file be read from?
4. What would be the consequence if the file is corrupt or deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/path/to/mysql/data/[database]/[table].ibd (due to innodb_file_per_table)
```

This is where you data are stored. They are created when you create the tables.

```
/path/to/mysql/data/data/ib_logfile0
/path/to/mysql/data/data/ib_logfile1
```

These are `logfiles`.

All data changes are written into the `logfiles` sequentially, which allows write-ahead logging (crucial for transactions)

```
/path/to/mysql/data/data/ibdata1
```

This is where system data and `UNDO` data are stored.

If `ibdata` is not found, `MySQL` will think that `InnoDB` engine is not initialized and just create the new `ibdata`. Same with `logfiles`.

If a query is issued against a table, and `.ibd` file is not found, `MySQL` will fail with this message:

> Cannot find table `database/table` from the internal data dictionary of `InnoDB` though the `.frm` file for the table exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated `InnoDB` data files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding `.frm` files of `InnoDB` tables, or you
>   have moved `.frm` files to another database?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know the answer to the last question as well (corruption/deletion)? Thanks in advance!